# Power calculation (a posteriori) of a cohort study - R software

Tags: r, statistical-power, case-cohort

Does anyone know if there's any R library to calculate the power of a cohort study with n=9511

Reference: **50 year trends in atrial fibrillation prevalence, incidence, risk
factors, and mortality in the Framingham Heart Study: a cohort study, Lancet 2015**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details concerning your question would be beneficial.

Anyway, there are many suitable packages in R, just look at the CRAN Task View on [Clinical Trials](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ClinicalTrials.html).

For instance, you can peruse the following pacakges: [pwr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html), [samplesize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/samplesize/index.html), and [TrialSize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TrialSize/index.html).